# JPA CriteriaBuilder - How to use "IN" comparison operator

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Can you please help me how to convert the following code to using "in" operator of criteria builder?
I need to filter by using list/array of usernames using "in".

*I also tried to search using JPA CriteriaBuilder - "in" method but cannot find good result.
So I would really appreciate also if you can give me reference URLs for this topic. Thanks.*

Here is my code:

```
//usersList is a list of User that I need to put inside IN operator 

CriteriaBuilder builder = getJpaTemplate().getEntityManagerFactory().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ScheduleRequest> criteria = builder.createQuery(ScheduleRequest.class);

Root<ScheduleRequest> scheduleRequest = criteria.from(ScheduleRequest.class);
criteria = criteria.select(scheduleRequest);

List<Predicate> params = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

List<ParameterExpression<String>> usersIdsParamList = new ArrayList<ParameterExpression<String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++) {
ParameterExpression<String> usersIdsParam = builder.parameter(String.class);
params.add(builder.equal(scheduleRequest.get("createdBy"), usersIdsParam) );
usersIdsParamList.add(usersIdsParam);
}

criteria = criteria.where(params.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

TypedQuery<ScheduleRequest> query = getJpaTemplate().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager().createQuery(criteria);

for (int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++) {
query.setParameter(usersIdsParamList.get(i), usersList.get(i).getUsername());
}

List<ScheduleRequest> scheduleRequestList = query.getResultList();
```

The internal Query String is converted to below, so I don't get the records created by the two users, because it is using "AND".

```
select generatedAlias0 from ScheduleRequest as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.createdBy=:param0 ) and ( generatedAlias0.createdBy=:param1 ) order by generatedAlias0.trackingId asc
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to Join `ScheduleRequest` with `User` and apply the `in` clause to the `userName` property of the entity `User`.

I'd need to work a bit on this schema. But you can try with this trick, that is much more readable than the code you posted, and avoids the `Join` part (because it handles the `Join` logic outside the Criteria Query).

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String> ();
for (User u : usersList) {
    myList.add(u.getUsername());
}
Expression<String> exp = scheduleRequest.get("createdBy");
Predicate predicate = exp.in(myList);
criteria.where(predicate);
```

In order to write more type-safe code you could also use Metamodel by replacing this line:

```
Expression<String> exp = scheduleRequest.get("createdBy");
```

with this:

```
Expression<String> exp = scheduleRequest.get(ScheduleRequest_.createdBy);
```

If it works, then you may try to add the `Join` logic into the `Criteria Query`. But right now I can't test it, so I prefer to see if somebody else wants to try.

Comment: Hi perissf, thanks for your reply. Can i ask please, what is "ScheduleRequest_"? How do i create it?

Comment: It's a Metamodel class auto-generated by your JPA provider. If you are using Hibernate, check out this link http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.0/reference/en-US/html_single/

Comment: Reading my pseudo-code I see a possible type discrepancy. Are you joining with userNames (String) or userIds (Integer / Long)? Pls let me know so that I can update my answer

Comment: Hi perissf, i'm using String userNames. I'm just following our architecture which don't have the "_" underscore bean, so I'm not sure how to do it. But will still try to follow your link. thanks.

Comment: thank you perissf, it worked for me. though I havent done the type-safe. I don't know how to auto-generate the class ScheduleRequest_. thank you very much! :)

Comment: Good to know! For the auto-generated classes, that are called Metamodel, have you read the link I have given to you? If you have problems on that, make a new question with the details

Comment: I am getting cannot cast to string error again and again using this

Comment: It works for my case, thanks a lot. I have struggled for this problem the whole morning!

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't use `in(List<String>)`.

Answer (score 21):

Not a perfect answer though may be code snippets might help.

```
public <T> List<T> findListWhereInCondition(Class<T> clazz,
            String conditionColumnName, Serializable... conditionColumnValues) {
        QueryBuilder<T> queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder<T>(clazz);
        addWhereInClause(queryBuilder, conditionColumnName,
                conditionColumnValues);
        queryBuilder.select();
        return queryBuilder.getResultList();

    }


private <T> void addWhereInClause(QueryBuilder<T> queryBuilder,
            String conditionColumnName, Serializable... conditionColumnValues) {

        Path<Object> path = queryBuilder.root.get(conditionColumnName);
        In<Object> in = queryBuilder.criteriaBuilder.in(path);
        for (Serializable conditionColumnValue : conditionColumnValues) {
            in.value(conditionColumnValue);
        }
        queryBuilder.criteriaQuery.where(in);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @gbagga, this thing helped me a lot! the above method (exp.in(myList)) will not work when you are using "CriteriaBuilder".

Your method is the one that should be used for "IN" clause when using criteriaBuilder. Kudos!