# JPA criteria subquery with common customerId field

Tags: mysql, jpa-2.0

How do I write the following MySQL query using JPA Criteria?

```
select * from deptors where customerId in 
   (select customerId from address where zipcode="12345-6789")
and gender="male";
```

I have read http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Subquery and many stackoverflow threads including [JPA 2.0, Criteria API, Subqueries, In Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions). But I am just not getting it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: For the `in` usage, also have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9325205/870122

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Deptors> cq = cb.createQuery(Deptors.class);
Root<Deptors> c = cq.from(Deptors.class);

Subquery<Address> subquery = cq.subquery(Address.class);
Root<Address> a = subquery.from(Address.class);
```

However I would rather recommend building this query with JPQL and/or externalize it as a NamedQuery into your Entity.

Sebastian