# How to pass list of arguments in criteriabuilder.equal method

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

Can you tell me if it's any way of using equal method in `CriteriaBuilder`  in that way :

`criteriaBuilder.equal( myClass.get("id") , HERE LIST STRINGS ARGUMETNS INSTEAD OF SINGLE STRING )` ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at this question. It looks like you want the in() operator not equal()

[JPA CriteriaBuilder - How to use "IN" comparison operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321916/jpa-criteriabuilder-how-to-use-in-comparison-operator)

Comment: It indeed has "IN" operator, but it's missing the "IN LIKE" operator ;/

Comment: @thorinkor That was not the question asked. He asked about multiple string "equal" restrictions.