# JPA2 Criteria - select element which has a collection with another element with specified value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria

There are two classes A and B. Class A has a collection of objects of class B in it. Class B has a field X. I'd like to be able to return list of objects of class A that have in their collections objects of type B having some specific value of their property X. Is it even possible?

So far I have tried something like:

```
Root<A> root = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root);
criteriaQuery.where(root.get("bCollection").get("x").in("value"))
```

but of course it does not work. How to handle this? Class B is mapped as a nested-component like this:

```
<set name="bCollection" table="bCollection">
            <key column="a_id" />
            <composite-element
                class="example.B">
                <many-to-one name="x" column="b_id" not-null="false"
                    cascade="none" foreign-key="b_fk" />
            </composite-element>
</set>
```

I hope someone knows... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible:

1. Create the root A (as you did).
2. Join the root A with B, obtaining a `Join B`.
3. Add the where condition, using the obtained `Join B`.

For examples of the IN clause, google or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321916/jpa-criteriabuilder-how-to-use-in-comparison-operator).

Comment: OK :)! But how to do the same if that collection of objects of type B is not directly in A, but in some class C inside class A? This class C is mapped as component so it doesn't add up to the hierarchy anything...