# JPA Criteria API "IN" Predicate not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api, jpa-criteria

I need to write the following with JPA Criteria API:

```
p.id IS NULL  AND   nv.organizationalstat IN ('EMPLOYEE', 'FELLOW')`
```

My code is:

```
 List<String> corePredicateInList = Arrays.asList("EMPLOYEE", "FELLOW");
 In<String> corePredicateIn = cb.in(nvRoot.get("organizationalstat"));
 corePredicateInList.forEach(p -> corePredicateIn.value(p)); // Setting opts into IN
 Predicate p1CorePredicate = cb.and( 
                                cb.isNull(plans.get("id")), 
                                cb.in(nvRoot.get("organizationalstat"), corePredicateIn)
                            );
```

The runtime error is

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: in
...
where ( ( ( ( ( ( generatedAlias0.id is null ) 
  and ( generatedAlias1.organizationalstat in (:param0, :param1) in () ) ) 
  or ( generatedAlias0.id is not null ) )
```

It looks like there's a double IN somewhere. There are no syntax errors in the code.

I can't do `cb.in(List<String>)` directly, that's wrong syntax. I have to go through `in.value()` as [indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9323183/1005607) in this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CriteriaBuilder.In`

```
Predicate p1CorePredicate = cb.and(cb.isNull(plans.get("id")),corePredicateIn);
```

Or using `Expression.In`

```
Predicate p1CorePredicate = cb.and(cb.isNull(plans.get("id")), 
                         nvRoot.get("organizationalstat").in(corePredicateInList));
```

Comment: Both options working. I prefer #2 because it lets me use my `List<String>` directly, without any other expressions. So I ended up using `root.get("..").in(stringList)`.

Comment: I totally agree with you, I added first one for showing how to solve you current problem. And just let you know for in query using subquery result `CriteriaBuilder.In` must need.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for me is to do `root.in(List<String>)` (not `cb.in`), as follows:

```
 List<String> corePredicateInList = Arrays.asList("EMPLOYEE", "FELLOW");
 Predicate p1CorePredicate = cb.and( 
                                cb.isNull(plans.get("id")), 
                                nvRoot.get("organizationalstat").in(corePredicateInList)
                            );
```